# JTextArea setText is not working

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a problem with setting text in JTextArea, I tried setText(which I'd prefer) and append also. I do not know where the problem is, I got client-server app. I want to put message that server sends in JTextField but I am unable to here is my code:

client side code which is reciving the message properly:

```
try
    {


        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader serverInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        output.writeBytes(outputString + "\n");
        inputString = serverInput.readLine(); // private String inputString
        mymodel.setTextArea(inputString); // this is not working
        System.out.println(inputString); // this is working
        socket.close();

    }
    catch...
```

setTextArea method:

```
public void setTextArea(String string)
{
    MyPanel mypanel = new MyPanel();
    mypanel.textArea.setText(string); // debugger shows that the string contains message from server
}
```

I have set textarea to public since setter method weren't working, actually this one isn't working also. I do not know where the problem is, and debugger isn't helping me either.

Looking for your answers

EDIT:

JTextTable code:

```
textArea = new JTextArea(1, 30);
textArea.setEditable(false);
panel.add(textArea, c);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get access through getter.
Like

```
public JTextArea getTextArea()
{
     return jTextAreaField;
}
```

and then

```
getTextArea().append("ur text");
```

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a new instance of `MyPanel` each time the `setTextArea` method is called, this means that what ever is on the screen isn't been used to apply the text you are sending it.

Instead, you should use the original instance of `MyPanel` that you created to show on the screen...

It's also impossible to determine if you are calling the blocking I/O from the content of the Event Dispatching Thread or interacting with the UI from a different thread. In either case, it's highly unrecommended

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Answer (score 2):

There are two main problems:

1. You perform the UI modification on the same thread as the IO, which you should never do. Consider working with [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for I/O operations.
2. In `setTextArea` you are not accessing the instance of `MyPanel` that you already have, but creating a new one. So the changes are not done in the `MyPanel` instance that you already have...

Comment: How can I access existing MyPanel instance from other class then?

Comment: If you follow the tutorial in my first point, it will be easier than hacking it (although absolutely possible)

Answer (score 1):

```
   JTextArea t=new JTextArea();
   t.append("Text");
   no Method in java to set Text for JTextArea.
   the append method to add text in JTextArea
```