# How to set text on textarea?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc

I am stuck in `up_address` line. I am working on a project for updating values in database, I am stuck in setting text in textarea.

```
 try{       
        int row = user_table.getSelectedRow();
        String Table_clicked =(String)(user_table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0));
        String sql="select * from userl where id ='"+Table_clicked+"' ";
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

        if(rs.next()){
            String up_nam= rs.getString("Name");
            up_name.setText(up_nam);
            String up_num= rs.getString("Number");
            up_number.setText(up_num);
            String up_cit= rs.getString("City");
            up_city.setText(up_cit);
            String up_addre= rs.getString("Address");
            up_address.setText(up_addre);

            String up_mod= rs.getString("Mode");
            up_mode.addItem(up_mod);
           String up_typ= rs.getString("Type");
            up_type.addItem(up_typ);
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "stuck", is it throwing some error, or not working as expected?

Comment: its not throwing any error and also not set any value in textarea

Comment: Why in few places `setText` and in few places `addItem` ?

Comment: Is the source of `Table_clicked` from a user? It looks like you might have a SQL injection security vulnerability there.

Comment: @Arulkumar additems belong to combobox

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the append function:

```
up_address.append(up_addre);
```

See this thread for more information: [JTextArea setText is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838734/jtextarea-settext-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

> its not throwing any error and also not set any value in textarea

How do you know it is not throwing any error?

You are using:

```
catch (Exception e) {}
```

You should NEVER do that since you will never know if you have an SQL problem.

You should at least be using:

```
catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
```

Also, using multiple text areas does not seem like an appropriate solution. I would suggest you should be using a JTable. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for basic information

Then you can also check out `Table From Database Example` found in [Table From Database](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for simple code that displays data from a database in a JTable.

Answer (score 0):

You Are Using `up_address.setText(up_addre);` In Loop , It Means Your JTextField Object up_address's value Will OverRidden If You Get More Then One Rows in rs(ResultSet Object).

And You Must Ensure That Field In Your Table "User1" Is Must be "**Address**"

You May Also try below Code
`try { // Put Your Code Here....
        }catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}`

It Will Help You If Any Error Occures....